# Cannot renew RHEL 7.6 Developer account subscription

Tags: subscription, rhel, rhel7

I'm having problems renewing an RHEL Developer account subscription, which expired a few days ago.
I performed the following steps, but still, subscription-manager notifies me that: `Unable to find available subscriptions for all your installed products.`

```
[qa@brendan ~]$ sudo subscription-manager remove --all
0 subscriptions removed at the server.
[qa@brendan ~]$ sudo subscription-manager unregister
Unregistering from: subscription.rhsm.redhat.com:443/subscription
System has been unregistered.
[qa@brendan ~]$ sudo subscription-manager clean
All local data removed
[qa@brendan ~]$ sudo subscription-manager register
Registering to: subscription.rhsm.redhat.com:443/subscription
Username: brendanjsonar
Password:
The system has been registered with ID: 7fe89b83-6ec2-423c-9476-062ab20d286a
The registered system name is: brendan.local
[qa@brendan ~]$ sudo subscription-manager refresh
All local data refreshed
[qa@brendan ~]$ sudo subscription-manager attach --auto
Installed Product Current Status:
Product Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server
Status:       Not Subscribed

Unable to find available subscriptions for all your installed products.
[qa@brendan ~]$
```

I also unregistered the system manually in https://access.redhat.com/management/systems, but the registration (with `sudo subscription-manager register --username brendanjsonar --auto-attach`) still complains `Unable to find available subscriptions for all your installed products.`

Any idea of how to renew my RHEL 7.6 system's registration?

Answer (score 0):

Log into developers.redhat.com and re-up on the T&Cs.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem was at RedHat.
I described the issue on https://access.redhat.com/discussions, and magically, after a few hours, I was able to renew my RHEL 7.6 Developer account subscription.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to first check with customer care of redhat or register for a new rhel developer account by using another email address .
Today my developer account subscription also ended .
So i registered with another email address & the issue is fixed .